# Is there a software or web server to calculate thermodynamic parameter enthalpy change of cellulase?

Tags: protein-structure, thermodynamics

I want to calculate thermodynamic paremeter enthalpy change of cellulase, but I don't know what software can do this work. Please tell me, thank you very much !

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please [edit] your question and clarify what exactly you mean by "thermodynamic paremeter". A thermodynamic parameter for what? And what parameter? Also, you have tagged this with 5 tags, are they really relevant to your question? What is the connection with structural variation for instance?

Comment: Enthalpy, how to calculate this by a software or a web server ? Thank you!

Comment: Again, the enthalpy of what? A folded RNA structure? The enthalpy of a chemical reaction? Please **[edit]** your question and clarify what you need.

Comment: This is the first question I asked, thank you for your advice.

Comment: 1) This looks more like computational chemistry. Not sure if we have experts here to answer this question. 2) Perhaps it will help if you clarify what kind of change; e.g. you can find enthalpy of formation and enthalpy of  combustion [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose)

Comment: Hi user239932, this looks like a pure biochemistry question, and would probably be better asked in [SE Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=enthalpy+protein) or [SE Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=enthalpy+protein), depending on what type of enthalpy you're looking for.

Comment: I'm against closing this question as off topic. Yes, it's borderline, but it involves computation and enzyme structure, and I'd hate to give people working at the interface of biochemistry/biophysics and structural protein/RNA informatics the impression that their questions are not welcome here. That said, the question is unclear. If the question is closed, this should be the reason.

Comment: I think question is fine, but @user239932 should edit it to make it answerable. Please, specify what exactly you want to compute. If you do not know, try to at least write why you want to do that. You can also skip "Please tell me, thank you very much !", we all believe that you are a nice person, kind behaviour is implicit here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [PISA](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/MG/ccp4mg_help/pisa.html) assuming you have a PDB file of cellulase? Sorry it's a short answer and should be a comment, I don't have the reputation, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it. What about YASARA＋FoldX ?